# spa on VS2013 learning

Tags: knockout.js, visual-studio-2013, offline, single-page-application

I work with vb.net for desktop application and  ASP.NET (vb and c#). I decided to learn MVC and SPA application.

I watched the Steven Sanderson presentation (published 2 years ago) and I think it is a fantastic technology.

I have created a MVC 4 - SPA project in VS2013 but the structure is completely different from the one presented by Sanderson.

1) I tried to implement the offline mechanism without success. Can anybody tell how can it be implemented ?

2) Is it possible that the 2013 MVC 4 (SPA) project uses different libraries now ? I can't use for example knockout and upshot in the sources. Am I missing some reference ?

3) Is there a tutorial/presentation more recent ?

I know there are lots of questions but I can't find documentation on-line that guides me step by step to create a new project.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Have a look at the Pluralsight courses by John Papa. http://www.pluralsight.com/courses/single-page-apps-jumpstart

Comment: I believe that upshot never made it past the CTP, have a look at breezejs which does the same job  as upshot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned by Nathan Fisher, I would also like to recomend http://www.pluralsight.com/courses/single-page-apps-jumpstart it's really good.. But maybe a better consideration would be to learn MVC, then learn Knockout/Angularjs/Whatever then use them togeter!

Also, don't learn MVC4, learn MVC5 (imo)

[MVC4 fundamentals](http://www.pluralsight.com/courses/mvc4) OR
[MVC5 fundamentals](http://www.pluralsight.com/courses/aspdotnet-mvc5-fundamentals)

[Knokcoutjs](http://www.pluralsight.com/courses/knockout-tips) OR [Anuglarjs](http://www.pluralsight.com/courses/angularjs-get-started)

Another goodie I can recomend is [Building a Site with Bootstrap, AngularJS, ASP.NET, EF and Azure](http://www.pluralsight.com/courses/site-building-bootstrap-angularjs-ef-azure)

If you don't have a pluralsight subscription, you can create a [trial here](https://www.pluralsight.com/a/subscribe/step1?isTrial=True)

Comment: Thanks everybody for your suggestions.